# How to fix a Flow 0.80.0 error with the DragLayer component from react-dnd?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I updated `flow-bin` from `0.54.0` to `0.80.0`, and now I'm seeing some new Flow errors from the `react-dnd` library. One example is the `DragLayer` higher-order component.

### Code:

```
// MyCustomDragLayer.jsx
// ----------------------------------------

import { DragLayer } from 'react-dnd'

class MyCustomDragLayer extends Component<Props> {
  // ...
}

export default DragLayer(monitor => ({
  item: monitor.getItem(),
  itemType: monitor.getItemType(),
  initialOffset: monitor.getInitialSourceClientOffset(),
  currentOffset: monitor.getSourceClientOffset(),
  initialClientOffset: monitor.getInitialClientOffset(),
  delta: monitor.getDifferenceFromInitialOffset(),
  isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
}))(MyCustomDragLayer)



// render() function in a different file
// ----------------------------------------

import DragLayer from './MyCustomDragLayer.jsx'

<DragLayer
  {...{
    prop_one,
    prop_two,
    // etc.
  }}
/>
```

### Flow Error:

```
Error ┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈┈ components/foo/bar.jsx:499:10

Cannot create DragLayer element because:
• property currentOffset is missing in props [1] but exists in object literal [2].
• property delta is missing in props [1] but exists in object literal [2].
• property initialClientOffset is missing in props [1] but exists in object literal [2].
• property initialOffset is missing in props [1] but exists in object literal [2].
• property isDragging is missing in props [1] but exists in object literal [2].
• ... 2 more errors.

    components/foo/index.jsx
    496│           }}
    497│         />
    498│
[1] 499│         <DragLayer
    500│           {...{
    501│             prop_one,
    502│             prop_two,
    503│             // etc.
    504│           }}
    505│         />
    506│

    components/foo/bar.jsx
[2] 410│ export default DragLayer(monitor => ({
    411│   item: monitor.getItem(),
    412│   itemType: monitor.getItemType(),
    413│   initialOffset: monitor.getInitialSourceClientOffset(),
    414│   currentOffset: monitor.getSourceClientOffset(),
    415│   initialClientOffset: monitor.getInitialClientOffset(),
    416│   delta: monitor.getDifferenceFromInitialOffset(),
    417│   isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
    418│ }))(MyCustomDragLayer)
```

How can I fix this Flow error?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I used $FlowFixMe on similar react-dnd 0.79.1 problem (not exactly the same) because I couldn't figure it out.  If you can't either, maybe it's a bug somewhere.

Sorry to not be too helpful, just giving backup that maybe it's not you.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I might have to add a $FlowFixMe and try a new release in the future. Might also be a good idea to open some issues on the Flow, flow-typed, and react-dnd repos.